# hide header bar from controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've created a new app using the following command:

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

added a `home.html` page to the `templates` folder, added the following to the `app.js` file:

```
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

and added the following controller:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
    $scope.me = "my name";
    //ionic.Platform.fullScreen(true, false);
    //$cordovaStatusbar.hide();
    //StatusBar.hide();
});
})
```

my `home.html`:

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
    <h3 style="margin-top:30px;">User Name {{me}}</h3>
    <select class="center" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Green</option>
        <option>Red</option>
    </select>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My question is how can I hide this top bar:
[image: ion bar]

just from a single page\view\controller?

**UPDATE**
changed my controller to this:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);
    $scope.me = "my name";
})
```

but still doesn't work even though the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/) say it's the correct way.

Comment: did you try this hide-nav-bar="true" inside your <ion-view> tag

Comment: What does your home.html look like?

Comment: @Muhsin where should I place it?

Comment: In your  <ion-view> directive(inside your home html page)

Comment: @Muhsin can this be done from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this,

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-content>
        <h3 style="margin-top:30px;">User Name {{me}}</h3>
        <select class="center" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <option>Blue</option>
            <option>Green</option>
            <option>Red</option>
        </select>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**or**

add this line in your contorller

```
$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);
```

[Refer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/)

Comment: this works, however, as the question title mentions I'd like to do it from the controller. is it possible?